# Possible change to Python Keyword Documentation and reference materials

Tags: python, keyword

How to get keyword lists was asked and answered years ago, but this relates to how keywords are documented and updated in Python.  In many languages, there is a help page containing each keyword with a hyperlink to help on that keyword.  I could have sworn Python had this too, but now I cannot find it.  Does it exist? and if so, can someone provide the hyperlink?

This URL helps you generate the list from the keyword library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.kwlist

But you then still have to look up each keyword one by one to find the help documentation.  From within iPython and other Python environments, this is not hard.  Just use `help()` on any keyword after generating the list.  But I am curious if there is a help page anywhere as described.  Does it still exist?

On a related note:

`True`, `False`, `None` behave like keywords in both Python 2 and Python 3 but testing shows they are only Keywords in Python 3.  `exec` and `print` converted from Python 2 keywords to builtin functions in Python 3 and Python 3 added the `nonlocal` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Python organization documentation site, the closest I think you will now come to what you are looking for is this URL.  Keywords are listed but not hyperlinked:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Perhaps the supposition in comments about the `keywords` library in combination with `help()` is correct.  Commands to know in this context:

```
# to get help on any individual keyword
help("some keyword")  # example:  help("yield")

# to find out all keywords or test if something is a keyword
import keywords
print(keyword.kwlist)

# to test if something is a keyword:
keyword.iskeyword("wordToTest")  # example: keyword.iskeyword("yield")
```

Regarding help documentation, others have taken up the mantle and you can find a page for Python 3 (that also gives a demo of the `keywords` library).  This webpage hyperlinks the keywords to help content about them:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list

Answer (score 0):

The `help()` function isn't limited to IPython. It's available in IDLE and the command-line interpreter.

`True`, `False` and `None` became reserved words in Python 3.

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True = 0
>>> True == False
True
```

but

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True = 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
```

So the difference is not an oversight.

Comment: The purpose of the code demo in your answer is to indicate that `True` is a builtin variable in Python 2.7 but a reserved keyword in Python 3?  Just clarifying for my understanding.

Comment: updated the related content at the end of my post based on your comments.  The question itself remains unanswered, but I am starting to suspect that maybe the reason is that the keywords library in combination with help() may have been intended to serve the function of the help page I am asking about.  Going to leave this question up there as unanswered to see if it attracts any attention from anyone who knows for sure.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: @undercovertek: yes, and a necessary change, as I tried to demonstrate